Calculate the limit of a function of two variables.
I can't calculate the limit in $(0,0)$ of the function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|x|}}$$
Can you help me please?

Do you mean $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}$ in the denominator? Also, you should include your effort in your post.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

In the exercise, it's $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|x|}$. I don't know if the exercise is wrong

$$0\leq\left|\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{\sqrt{|x|} + \sqrt{|y|}}\right| \leq \frac{|\sin(x)|}{\sqrt{|x|}} = \sqrt{|x|}\times\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)} 0\times 1 = 0$$
